# How can cassandra choose which node on cluster to perform read/write operation?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using Cassandra datastax java API, and I wonder how it chooses which node on the cluster to write or read data. For example, if I execute (via Session) the write operation 1000 times, will all the operations go to the same node? Or it will choose the node to perform the execution randomly ?

If it allowed us to perform read/write on the node we want, following on specific patter (e.g. round robin writing...), which is the best option we can choose to speed up the writing process?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partitioning key of the record defines which node is responsible for storing the data, and for doing queries on it. That is why you need to give the full partitioning key in `WHERE` criteria, or do a full table scan.

So essentially, you do not choose the node yourself explicitly, but implicitly by specifying the partitioning key in read/write operations.

Comment: Then can we force to the behavior we want above by using clustering key? E.g. the the record from 1 to 1000, cluster key is A, and the records from 1001 to 2000, cluster key is B

Comment: @Xitrum While the *partitioning* key defines which node is reponsible for the data, the *clustering* key does the ordering of records on that node. If you want to force all your data on one node, give the table a partitioning key column called "alwaysOne", with its content always being 1. However, I would strongly recommend against it. "If you cannot distribute it, you cannot scale it."